# Laravel Relationship columns of the same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am creating a table to store parent category and its children (submenu).

I am trying to relate the "submenu" column to the "id" column of the same table.

I will use this relationship to build a submenu menu using a foreach.

My MySQl Table:

```
ID | submenu | name
1  | null    | Products
2  | 1       | Submenu Level 1 (A)
3  | 1       | Submenu Level 1 (B)
4  | null    | Phones
5  | 4       | Samsung
6  | 4       | Apple
```

Now i select all fathers.

```
$categorias = Categorias::withCount('submenu')->where('ativo', 1)->whereNull('submenu')->get();
```

Now I can not continue.

I would like to do this.

```
<ul>
  @foreach($categorias as $n1){
    <li>
      <a href="">{{ $n1->name }}</a> // Here work
        @if( $n1->submenu_count > 0 )
          <ul>

            // I can't do this.
            @foreach($n1->submenus() as $n2)
              <li> <a href="">{{ $n2->nome }} </li>
            @endforeach


          </ul>
        @endif
    </li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Here are some ways I tried to do in the model.

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Categorias','submenu');
}

public function submenu(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Categorias','submenu');
}

public function submenu(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Categorias', 'id', 'submenu');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do so

```
public function submenus(){
    return $this->hasMany(Categorias::class,'submenu', 'id');
}

$categorias = Categorias::with('submenus')->whereNull('submenu')->get();
```